# inspect python object source code without comments

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, introspection

A library I'd like to use seems to get confused by triple quote comments when introspecting python code. It appears that Python's inspect doesn't give access to de-commented code though?

[This code in Hyperas breaks](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas/blob/master/hyperas/optim.py#L61-L64) and looks un-pythonic but I can't figure out how it could  be done better.  Is AST the way forward?

Comment: What library is it, and in what way does it get confused?  Triple-quoted strings aren't comments. they're string literals.  You can *use* them like comments, but they're not the same.

Comment: It's Hyperas inside Jupyter as mentioned in this issue: https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas/issues/28

Comment: Can you add an example of what you are trying to ignore? You could probably do it pretty easily by using  StringIO object to read from removing sections starting with triple quotes until the closing.

Comment: I think the question is too complicated to be answered based on the information you've provided here.  On the other issue linked from that one, the author of the library says "Right now I don't have a great idea on how to fix this without doing something really awkward. Actually, I hope to rewrite hyperas at some point to resolve this."  To get any answers on this you'd need to post more specific examples of what exact code is failing and how.  Also, based on that issue, I don't see how the problem is related to triple-quoted strings.